# The path of file correct but it show 404 page and this error

Tags: php, laragon

I don't understand this error and how to fix

> Warning: require(views/index.view.php): Failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory in C:\laragon\www\php_prac\controllers\index.php on
> line 5
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
> 'views/index.view.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in
> C:\laragon\www\php_prac\controllers\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\laragon\www\php_prac\controllers\index.php on line 5

it should show home page

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory. The file you're trying to load doesn't exist in the path you've specified. If you share the code that causes the error and the file/folder structure, it will be easier for us to help.